# g++ in WSL has created an undeleteable file

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I compiled a basic C++ file 'simple.cpp' into an executable 'simple' using g++ under WSL (`g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0`). After creating this executable, I am unable to delete it.

I've tried deleting with `rm -rf simple`, `sudo rm -rf simple`, deleting via Windows Explorer (the security tab is missing in properties) and `del simple` in an elevated Command Prompt. Interestingly, `sudo rm -rf simple` returns 0, indicating sucess, but `ls -l` shows the file is still there, but unreadable. even to `sudo ls -l` it displays the following:

```
ls: cannot access 'simple': No such file or directory
total 128
-????????? ? ?   ?    ?            ? simple
-rwxrwxrwx 1 seb seb 28 Aug  6 17:25 simple.cpp
```

Attempting to chmod or chown the file fails with `cannot access 'simple': No such file or directory` as well.

The `simple.cpp` file contains the very innocuous:

```cpp
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that one of the 4 methods described would get rid of the file, but everything fails.

Comment: `rm -rf simple` - why the `r` (which means recursive) argument? That only makes sense for directories and `simple` is a file, not a directory. Not that it really matters, just seems strange to specify pointless arguments to commands.

Comment: If a Windows application has the file open it would probably prevent deletion.. just a guess.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the -r was because the file was being reported as a directory by some commands I used, so I thought I'd remove that as a potential issue by using -r to delete it if it had in fact become a directory somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually due to a process having a handle to the file.
You could try to kill said process but I would recommend just restarting your computer and trying to delete the file

Comment: Restarting it actually made the file disappear, interestingly, if I try and delete the file initially with Windows Explorer there are no problems.

Comment: It also appears that the offending program is Visual Studio Code, as restarting that program causes the file to disappear, but also seems to break WSL in Visual Studio Code for that folder.